# How to find a language direction?

Tags: multi-language, language

The function `is_rtl()` checks the blog language direction if it is LTR or RTL.

```
public function is_rtl() {
    return 'rtl' == $this->text_direction;
}
```

But I couldn't find where or who fills in the `text_direction` data.
If I change the blog language to Arabic then `text_direction` becomes RTL. Where does it get the language direction information from?

The language list data is retrieved from the trasnaltions api https://api.wordpress.org/translations/core/1.0/ but that doesn't include the language direction!

Is there another API for this? How can I get the direction of a language that is not set as the blog language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text_direction` property of [the `WP_Locale` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_locale/) defaults to `'ltr'` as per [it's declaration](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/locale.php#L78), then may be modified in the class's `init()` initialization function in [`wp-includes/locale.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/locale.php#) (near [line #207 in WP 4.5](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-includes/locale.php#L207)) with the following logic:

```
// Set text direction.
if ( isset( $GLOBALS['text_direction'] ) )
    $this->text_direction = $GLOBALS['text_direction'];
/* translators: 'rtl' or 'ltr'. This sets the text direction for WordPress. */
elseif ( 'rtl' == _x( 'ltr', 'text direction' ) )
  $this->text_direction = 'rtl';

if ( 'rtl' === $this->text_direction && strpos( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '-src' ) ) {
  $this->text_direction = 'ltr';
  add_action( 'all_admin_notices', array( $this, 'rtl_src_admin_notice' ) );
}
```

Using the initialization logic above, WordPress changes the text direction to the value of the `$text_direction` global, if it exists. Failing that, it applies [the `_x()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_x) to retrieve the localized value of the string `'ltr'` with the context of `'text direction'`.

So, more often than not, the text direction is set by the translation files for the selected language. [Here](https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp/dev/ar/default?filters[status]=either&filters[original_id]=40305&filters[translation_id]=9704861) you can see the text direction translation for Arabic in the web-based interface for core translation.

After determining the language to use, WordPress uses [the `load_default_textdomain()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_default_textdomain) to provide access to the configured locale's language data through the `$l10n` global, which the localization functions then rely upon for translations.

Determining the language direction for non-default languages by the same means that WordPress does requires [a multi-language installation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress). Many of the methods detailed in the linked Codex entry switch out the active locale on the fly, so the active language's text direction is always available by `_x( 'ltr', 'text-direction' );`.

Alternately, if you need to get the direction of inactive languages, you could [install the translation file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language#Manually_Installing_Language_Files) for every language whose text direction you wish to acquire, then create instances of the `Mo` class and invoke `import_from_file()` to keep language data separated, after which a call to `$mo->translate( 'ltr', 'text_direction' );` would return the language's text direction, if set.

Depending on why you need to acquire the text direction of unloaded languages, it would likely be much more efficient and less resource-intensive to compile a static list of language directions before-hand.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, I never expected the direction to be stored in the translation file!. I thought WP had its own static list that I was trying to find to read from. I will generate my own list then.

Comment: And to explain why I need this, because I have a blog in English, but I write some posts in Arabic. And if the title of the Arabic post that has some English words in it the default LTR direction misses it up. And I am trying to make a plugin that sets the direction based on the language when showing the front page which has posts of mixed languages.